Vacuum is tripping breaker on a different circuit
Why would a breaker trip when vacuuming? The kicker is the vacuum still works, because it is plugged in on a different circuit. Breaker being trip is the family room breaker. Which had 4 can lights, OLED TV, ring alarm, cable box, security nvr, light hub, and Ethernet switch. Not all are always on. Breaker tripping is a GAFCI 15 amp Siemens breaker. Breaker that vacuum is plugged into is either a 15 amp Siemens single pole breaker or 20 amp Siemens single pole breaker. I haven’t changed anything on my breaker panel recently. Breakers are about 9 years old. I do hear a “noise” like a small arc coming from the 20 amp single pole breaker. The fridge is on this breaker. As well as the gas range. Dishwasher breaker has some kind of metal thing around the breaker. Family room lights have always flickered when vacuuming.

Does it with air fryer too. But if an electric mop is plugged in, no problems.

This is a classic Arc Fault situation.

GAFCI = GFCI and AFCI. Unless something is really, really wrong (mixed neutrals or neutral/ground bonded where it shouldn't be, both of which would trip the GFCI immediately and consistently) this is not GFCI. Which means it is AFCI - Arc Fault Circuit Interrupter. There should be some sort of light/code on the breaker to tell you that it is specifically an arc fault, but I'm pretty sure of it.
I do hear a "noise" like a small arc coming from the 20 amp single pole breaker. - That may be real or imagined, as an AFCI can detect arcs that are invisible to the naked eye and inaudible to the human ear. But it does fit the basic problem.
Family room lights have always flickered when vacuuming. - That is also indicative of either arcing or a very high power draw from the vacuum cleaner causing power fluctuations.

All of this put together points to the vacuum cleaner producing sufficient power line noise that it is interpreted as an arc fault on a nearby circuit. Unlike GFCI which measures current (or really the balance in current on two or three wires), an AFCI is "listening" for noise, which can be induced or conducted from nearby wires.
The GAFCI may be a little oversensitive. Or the vacuum cleaner may be having serious problems and need to be replaced. My guess is somewhere in between or a little of each. Vacuum cleaners tend to have big motors because you want lots of power! They tend to have electrically noisy motors because you use it for a few minutes so who cares if the lights blink and the radio crackles while it runs. They also tend to be audibly noisy as well, but that is not directly related to this problem, except in the sense that you can make a motor: powerful, high-quality (minimize electrical noise and audible noise) or inexpensive - pick 2 out of 3. Most people don't know anything about electrical noise. They may know about audible noise (measured in decibels) but while low noise is a selling feature on a bathroom or kitchen fan, it doesn't really matter much for a vacuum cleaner. So vacuum cleaners are sold based on basic features (canister vs. upright, how many attachments, etc.), power (more is better) and price (lower is better).
You may want to check with the Siemens to find out if there are any adjustments or newer breakers (warning: these are expensive breakers) or if they have any other suggestions. Other than that, live with occasional trips or get a new vacuum cleaner and hope it does better.

I recently wired up a 14-50R, which is running on AL wire. I did buy an Eaton outlet which was designated for AL wire. However the 14-50R outlet hasn’t had a charger plugged in when the breaker in question has tripped. I also added WiFi6 security cameras. Could any of these things be causing the noise? I also added two more items to one of the outlet that is on the circuit tripping. I do have two power strips plugged together on one socket. But the items plugged in shouldn’t be drawing that much power.

Anything is possible. But wires with no load (14-50R no charger plugged in, by the way I always recommend a hardwired charger but that's irrelevant at the moment) should not have any effect on a GAFCI on another circuit. And WiFi cameras, etc. are teeny tiny loads and on the types of power supplies that are extremely unlikely to cause GAFCI problems, especially on another circuit. But large motor loads? Sure - and that includes the vacuum cleaner and air fryer.

I have the wire to hard wire the charger. Just haven’t done it yet. The weirdest part is the fact the vacuum and air fryer do not trip the breaker they are plugged into. The breaker tripping is the family room with usually only the TV and living room lights running.

Well I guess the ring alarm and internet items are running on the tripping breaker too. But like I said should be minimal loads.

Is it possible that a cumulative effect of various loads can trigger the problem? Yes. Definitely with GFCI, not as much with AFCI. But start with what you know: Running the vacuum cleaner causes the breaker to trip. Occam would say "it is probably the vacuum cleaner".

Okay. But the air fryer same outlet has the same result. If I plug the vaccum into another breaker “further” away no issue. The family room breaker trips if the vaccum is plugged into the closest north nearby outlet (different breaker than family room). Family room trips. Plug vaccum into master bedroom out let 2 outlets north of family, family room break will not trip. I am at a loss, thus the back and forth.

That all makes perfect sense. Even though this is electrical noise not audible noise, the concept is much the same - the farther away it is, the less the GAFCI breaker can "hear" it. If it was on the same circuit then it would be expected to "hear" it anywhere on the circuit. Since it is on a different circuit, it makes sense that distance will matter more. Compare it to shouting down a hallway ("same" circuit) vs. shouting through a wall nearby ("different" circuit but close) vs. shouting through a wall a few rooms down the hallway ("different" + "far away"). TL;DR vacuum is tripping, vacuum

is the problem. With possibility of over-sensitive breaker.

@JasonHiatt he does not know, just wildly guessing around

If you've ever hooked up speakers with the amplifier power turned on and heard the crinkle-crunch sound, you've experienced an arc fault.  You know both what it is and what it "sounds like" when the electromagnetic wave is converted to sound waves (which convert very well; it's what speakers do).
You probably know digital signal processing is pretty good these days.  Well, that's what an AFCI breaker is. It's doing DSP to recognize that crinkle-crunch "sound" on the wires.
Most arc faults are "series arc faults" meaning the arcing is inline in the wires due to a loose or faulty connection.  It is only there if a load is there.  And the bigger the load, the more likely and detectable the arc fault is.
However, it's unavoidable that an AFCI can "hear" arcing on the LINE (input) side of the breaker.  Thus, AFCIs have the weird (but still helpful) tendency to trip from arc faults on other circuits.  So an arcing fault in that circuit is causing the ACFI to trip.  Weird, but true.
You can dismiss this as "Aww, vacuum cleaners trip AFCIs all the time, let's just call it that and sleep soundly".  Well maybe.  But it could also be a genuine arcing fault on the circuit.

But why would this all of sudden? Further information… The breaker in question didn’t flip tonight when the air fryer was used. The breaker in question has tripped before when the Treager was starting up outside the living room.

@JasonHiatt A seres arc fault only happens when current is moving through it.  Howwever as my answer discusses, AFCI breakers are antennas that can detect arcing happening on other circuits.  Why do circuits NOT arc-fault then suddenly start?  That's a mystery, countless 14-50 sockets installed for EVs run for months or years then suddenly melt.  That's why we don't like sockets and say to hardwire EVs.
